# Ansible: any file from dictionary

Tags: ansible

Today I totally broke my brain with that. I have some structure with dictionary files and I need to make some text or json with variables which uses in dictionary:

```
> hosts_vars
    varfile.yaml
> inventory
    hosts.yml
tasks.yml
```

*varfile.yaml*

```
host_vars:
 host1: { ip: 192.168.1.1 }
 host2: { ip: 192.168.1.2 }
```

*hosts.yml*

```
all:
  hosts:
    host1:
      ansible_host: 192.168.1.1
    host2:
      ansible_host: 192.168.1.2
```

*tasks.yml*

```
- hosts: all
  become: no
  gather_facts: false
  vars_files:
    - hosts_vars/varfile.yaml
  vars:
   temp_file: /tmp/out_file.txt
  tasks:
   - local_action:
      module: ansible.builtin.lineinfile
      path: '{{ temp_file }}'
      line: |
         - targets: ['{{ host_vars[inventory_hostname].ip }}']
      state: present
```

When I run it: `ansible-playbook tasks.yml -l all`
I got:

```
~> cat /tmp/out_file.txt

- targets: ['192.168.1.1']
```

I didn't understand why it happened. When if I had 60 hosts I'll got ~54 lines in file. How it works?

Comment: Not really related to your issue at hand, but still: why do you repeat the same information in your inventory and in a variable file? DRY it and use `ansible_host` to populate your file.

Comment: Also, is `out_file.txt` supposed to be a YAML? It has its format, but I am wondering if it is due to an oversimplification of your issue to make it fit SO's scope or if it is your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the file in localhost and delegate the task to localhost looping hosts.

```
  tasks:
   -  name: update host
      lineinfile:
        path: '{{ temp_file }}'
        create: yes
        line: |
         - targets: ['{{ host_vars[item].ip }}'] # or ['{{ host_vars[item]['ip'] }}']
        insertafter: EOF
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
      with_inventory_hostnames:
        - all
```

Comment: Interesting way. Thank you. My way works well, I put a comment about /tmp folder issue on macOS.

Answer (score 1):

For example

```yaml
  tasks:
    - ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
        create: yes
        path: "{{ temp_file }}"
        line: "- targets: ['{{ host_vars[inventory_hostname].ip }}']"
      delegate_to: localhost
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/out_file.txt
- targets: ['192.168.1.2']
- targets: ['192.168.1.1']
```

Notes:

- Don't use [Yaml Literal Style](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#812-literal-style) block with [*line*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html#parameter-line). It says what it is. You don't want any newlines `\n` in the line. If you for whatever reason have to use the block put dash `-` behind the pipe `|`. This will remove the trailing newline `\n`

```yaml
    - ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
        create: true
        path: "{{ temp_file }}"
        line: |-
          - targets: ['{{ host_vars[inventory_hostname].ip }}']
      delegate_to: localhost
```

- You can use [*delegate_to: localhost*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegating-tasks) instead of *local_action*
- Use [*create: yes*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html#parameter-create). It is `no` by default and the task will fail `Destination /tmp/out_file.txt does not exist !` if the file doesn't exist.
- [*state: present*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html#parameter-state) is default
- [*insertafter: EOF*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html#parameter-insertafter) is default
- Putting *varfile.yaml* into the directory *host_vars* is missing the point how [*host_vars*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variables) work. There is no host with the name `varfile`. You should put the file, e.g. into `vars/varfile.yaml` instead.
- The variable *host_vars* is redundant. The IP of the hosts is stored in the variable *ansible_host*. The task below gives the same result

```yaml
    - ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
        create: true
        path: "{{ temp_file }}"
        line: "- targets: ['{{ ansible_host }}']"
      delegate_to: localhost
```

- If you'd like to create a list of all IP addresses the task below

```yaml
    - ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
        create: true
        path: "{{ temp_file }}"
        line: "- targets: {{ ansible_play_hosts_all|
                             map('extract', hostvars, 'ansible_host') }}"
      run_once: true
      delegate_to: localhost
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/out_file.txt
- targets: ['192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2']
```

Comment: Thank you. It's very helpful for me. I didn't know about newlines )

Answer (score 0):

macOS with ansible [core 2.11.2] had issue with write files in `/tmp` If you want to use this you need to set the home folder or any other folder with root permissions.